# Should I change an existing question completely to get out of purgatory?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, closed-questions

I asked a question on META about the notorious question ban and linked a question that received 3 down votes. Linking it here doubled the amount of down votes (though I was just using it for reference to ask what was bad about it). It was finally closed.

**So should I change that question completely**? Delete it? I have been answering questions and got my rep above 200 but I still cannot ask questions on stackoverflow

Excluding that now -6 question, I have 3 up votes and 5 down votes on my questions. I'm starting to think answering questions isn't going to help. I'm pretty sure I was punished for a question I deleted 5 minutes after posting as well (I saw the error and deleted it so I wouldn't waste peoples time).

`<sigh>`. I just want help with a confusing php question :/ I've spent so much time on here the past few days it's risen to my #1 most visited :(.

Comment: You've got 200 rep and are question-banned?  Hold on while I check your account.

Comment: Sorry, but your accounts are not linked, and Casey Hodge doesn't look up on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you, http://stackoverflow.com/users/1591067/kcdwayne

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes for some reason it wouldn't accept the e-mail when I tried to ask my first question on META.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you've got a lot of downvoted questions there, chief.

Although your questions are clear and well-written, they strike me as dealing with basic, neophyte programming issues.  If your questions are so basic that you need to go read a book on PHP first, it could explain why the community is receiving them negatively.  You may want to re-evaluate your question-asking approach.

In any case, the community team informs me that, at the moment, you are no longer question-banned.  Some nice people must have given you some free upvotes.

Comment: Thank you so much and everyone that has helped out. My questions will be a lot better now that I understand the community a bit better.